# Pattern for hierarchical settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, design-patterns, settings, hierarchy

Assume the software has a hierarchy of settings:

```
- system settings
-- company settings
--- department settings
```

A few of the parent settings are default settings for the child and can be overwrite.

What is best practice to store the settings in the database and how should the code structure looks like?

I'm thinking about to store the settings as key/value with option to set as default. Many settings are combined to a setting-set which references to one of the hierarchy. 
In code e.g. I would get the setting-set from a company and search for one required setting. If the required setting is NULL I would look for the required default setting in the system setting-set.

I'd appreciate any suggestion / patterns in that regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot that can be done here. It depends from your actual design and goals. One possible solution form the *Behavioral* point is the [State design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/state-design-pattern), since it's alter an object's behavior when its state changes. I'm currently using it to keep the

> default for the child and can be overwrite

depending form the State that currently is going through. If you want to just load the corresponding set I think this is a good solution.

But if you need to use *Creational* approach in

> store the settings in the database

than the [Abstract factory](http://www.dofactory.com/net/abstract-factory-design-pattern) is one way to go. it'll allow you to creates an instance of several families of classes and will provide an interface for creating families of related or dependent objects without specifying their concrete classes (so you can achieve overwrite).

The [Composite](http://www.dofactory.com/net/composite-design-pattern) will help you to create your tree-like structure of simple and composite objects and represent this part-whole hierarchy. Composite lets clients treat individual objects and compositions of objects uniformly.

I know that this is abstract solution, but the concepts can do the job just right.